# Storing independent data tables in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have put ~100 dataframes containing data into a list `tables` and a list of names (so I can call by name or just iterate over the whole bunch without needing names)

This data will need to be stored, appended to and later queried. So I want to store it as a pandas hdf5 store.

There are ~100 DFs but I can group them into pairs (two different observers).

In the end I want to iterate over all the list of tables but also

I've thought about Panels (but that will have annoying NaN values since the tables aren't the same length), hierachical hd5f (but that doesn't really solve anything, just groups by observer), one continuous dataframe (seeming as they have the same number of columns) (but that will just make it harder because I'll have to piece the DFs back together afterwards).

Is there anything blatantly obvious I'm missing, or am I just going to have to grin and bear it with one these? (if so which one would you go for to give the greatest flexibility?)

Thanks

Comment: seems natural to store each in a single node in an HDF5 file. As long as you don't need to cross query this works well. (and if you DO need to cross query then you SHOULD combine them).

Comment: You could also construct a `MultiIndex` and use `groupby` to iterate over the subsets of the index.